# Opening Task Manager quickly

Tags: windows-7, task-manager

To open Task Manager, I press `Ctrl+Alt+Del` and then select *Start Task Manager*.

I would much prefer to have a shortcut on my desktop and avoid the `Ctrl+Alt+Del`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Right Click on your desktop
2. Choose "New" and "Shortcut"
3. For the location, type "taskmgr.exe" and click "Next"
4. Type in a name for the shortcut, something like "Task Manager"
5. Click "Finish"

Enjoy your new splendid desktop shortcut to Task Manager!

Answer (score 10):

No need for a desktop shortcut:

- Press `Ctrl-Shift-Escape` to open Task Manager.
- You can also right-click the task bar and select *Task Manager* (or *Start Task Manager*) there.

Comment: Good answer, but it would ne nice to have a short cut which you could display a specific tab.

Comment: @dublintech you can always just minimise the task manager to the tray instead of closing it when you need it more often.